# Clistview in yii Undefined variable dataProvider

Tags: listview, yii, dataprovider

I need a list view in my **index.php**. This is does not have any model so I used **CSqlDataProvider** for declaring the data provider and rendering it to the index from the controller. Here is my controller action...

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $sql="select * from Ads";
        $totalItemCount=20;
        $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                'totalItemCount' => $totalItemCount,
                                )); 

        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
}
```

Here is my index.php code....

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'index',
    'id'=>'list',
    ));
```

I am getting an error

> "Undefined variable: dataProvider"

Comment: Try var_dump($dataProvider) before render function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `itemView` cannot be `index`. It has to be a partial view that will render the items in your list. `$dataProvider` is available when the list is being rendered but not when the items are being rendered hence the error. For more information http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemView-detail