# undefined variable when variable is defined yii

Tags: yii

Is this not defined?! It says dataProvider is not defined. Btw, I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979058/clistview-in-yii-undefined-variable-dataprovider). Does it mean I have to list each items in view? Not following what it's saying.

noob question. Sorry.

```
  public function actionIndex()
{
    $id=1;

    $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider(array(
            array('product_name'=>Product::model()->product_name,
                'inventory_id'=>Product::model()->inventory_id,
                'product_price'=>Product::model()->product_price,
    ),

    $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ))
    ));     

}
```

view

```
<div class="widget-body">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
             'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'columns'=>array(
                array('name'=>'product_name', 'header'=>'Product Name'),
                 array('name'=>'inventory_id', 'header'=>'Inventory ID'),
                array('name'=>'product_price', 'header'=>'Price'),
                array(
                     'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
                ),
                ),
    )); ?>
```

Comment: you should use TbGridView for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TbDetailView` is supposed to display a single model, you don't need any data provider for it.

Controller code:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $id=1;

    $this->render('index', array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'product_name',
        'inventory_id',
        'product_price',
    ),
)); ?>
```