# scroll pager extension In Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, infinite-scroll, pager

i am using Yii2 with a scroll pager extension: http://kop.github.io/yii2-scroll-pager/

Here's my code:

```
echo yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $boards,
    'itemView' => 'boards',
    'layout' => $template,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'pager' => ['class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className()]
]);
```

and i am seetting dataProvider from modal The Code is given below

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Boards::find(),
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 3),
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
```

But i am getting the following exception

PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined variable: boards

Can any when tell me what is the wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979058/clistview-in-yii-undefined-variable-dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

Is $boards defined?

From what i figure

```
'dataProvider' => $boards,
```

is not defined, i do not think it has anything to do with ScrollPager. Try removing

```
'pager' => ['class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className()]
```

you will probably get the same error.